# Access the contents from third table to has_many_and_belongs_to association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have semester and subject model and they have has_many_and_belongs_to association. semester table has only semester_name column and subject table has only subject_name column. Third table name semesters_subjects and it has subject_id and semester_id column. 
If my semesters_subjects has following data in the table

```
subject_id  semester_id column
1                   2
1                   3
1                   7
2                   4
2                   3
```

that is one subject can exist in many semester. Now I want to find the semester_id where subject_id = 1 or if I want to find subject_id where semester_id = 3

In rails how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's many to many relation ship.

```
@semester = Semester.find(3)
@semester.subjects # will return all semester subjects you can add 
# where clause or pluck id as per your need
# similarly for subject
@subject  = Subject.find(1)
@subject.semesters  #will return subject semesters
```